# Converting integer into float to calculate new values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, floating-point, subtraction

I created a subset of a Pandas DataFrame in Python with four columns. Then, I wanted to measure the distance from every person in the main DataFrame to the subset.

```
df_all['dist_2021'] = np.sqrt( (df_all_subset["PCA1"] - df_all['PCA1'])**2)
```

Didn't work. Only got NaNs. I ultimately solved it by creating a new variable for every number in the subset and converting it into float. But I don't understand why that worked...

```
subset_pca1 = float(df_all["PCA1"][(df_all["Player"] == "Jadon Sancho") & (df_all["Season"] == "2020/2021")])
```

Can someone explain? Also, more generally, is this the typical way of how to subtract one dataframe from another?

Comment: Python and Pandas

Comment: [edit] the question, and also add the tags for that.

Comment: Also this is not a [mcve]. You didn't define `df_all`...

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Python -- what needs to be defined there?

Comment: Read the link above. Basically make sure we can copy paste and run your code, and that it isn't too long.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.